# Python 3 equivalent of Python 2 urllib.urlencode

Tags: python, urllib, urllib2

I'm making a POST request to a remote server using Python 2.7 and Python 3 and getting different responses in each scenario. Could the issue be how the data in each request is being encoded? What's the Python 3 equivalent of what I'm doing in 2.7?

```
// Python 2.7
data = {'username':'test'}
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
print(data)

req = urllib2.Request(base_link + 'inf.cgi', data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
mypage = response.read()
```

user=test

```
// Python 3
data = {'username':'test'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode("utf-8")
print(data)
base_link = 'http://tax1.co.monmouth.nj.us/cgi-bin/'

# Make HTTP request
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
mypage = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
```

b'user=test'

Trying this without encoding the data:

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
```

gives a similar output to that in 2.7:

user=test

but results in an error when making the POST request: 'TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.'

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question: The issue here is a difference between py2 & 3 string & byte handling in `urlencode` and the print statement. In py2 urlencode returns bytes, but the print statement doesn't format them as bytes. In py3 it returns a string, which is why you need to encode it. (Or pass it bytes-only params like `data = {b'username': b'test'}`

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for `urllib.parse`. This is an example of a code that I use.

```
address = urllib.parse.quote(address, safe='/:=?&', encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
address = urllib.request.urlopen(address).read().decode('utf8')
```

Comment: I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/parse.py", line 804, in quote
    raise TypeError("quote() doesn't support 'encoding' for bytes")
TypeError: quote() doesn't support 'encoding' for bytes